# Ruby on Rails : non-resourceful route working,but haml page fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, haml

So I have the following code in my routes.rb file:

```
match "/movies/:id/find_similar_movies", :to => "movies#similar", :as => "find_similar_movies"
```

then in a haml page I have the following:

```
= link_to 'Find Movies With Same Director', find_similar_movies_path(:id=>@movie.id)
```

then in my controller I have:

```
def similar
    movie=Movie.find_by_id([params(:id)])
    @movie_title=movie.title
    @similar_movies=Movie.find_all_by_director(movie.director)
  end
```

and in the similar.html.haml I write:

```
%h2 Similar movies with #{@movie_title}
%ul
- @similar_movies.each do |movie|
  %li = movie
= link_to 'Back to movie list', movies_path
```

when I press the `= link_to 'Find Movies With Same Director', find_similar_movies_path(:id=>@movie.id)`

I get:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/hw4_rottenpotatoes
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:10:in `similar'

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"6"}

What's wrong?Thanks for your time...

Comment: It most likely means there's an error somewhere in your `find_similar_movies` action, but without the full error message and matching code, it's hard to tell

Comment: what do you mean by find_similar_movies action?I have no more code concerning the similar page

Comment: I mean the `similar` action sorry. But yeah, we need the full error message that can be found either in the browser or the rails server

Comment: Another way to write a route like this would be inside of a `resources :movies do` block; for example `get 'find_more_similar', :on => :member'`.  This shortcut will automatically recognize the path /movies/:id/find_more_similar with GET, route to the find_more_similar action of the MoviesController, and generate the helper find_more_similar_movies_path.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto: Have you found anything?Do you need any more info?I've added the error code shown in my browser to my initial post.

Comment: I'd need to know what's the line number 10 in `app/controllers/movies_controller.rb`

Comment: movie=Movie.find_by_id([params(:id)])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params(:id)` is trying to call a method called `params` with an `:id` argument, which is not how this works. `params` should be treated like a hash, the lookup syntax for which is `params[:id]`.

Try `Movie.find_by_id(params[:id])`.